# GET API callout in test classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api

I have a web service callout that checks if an order’s type is return and needs to see what the actual boughtPrice is:

```
webservice static String updateBoughtPrice(Id ordId){
  Decimal boughtPrice = Orders.grabBoughtPrice(order.Buyer__r.email);

 if (order.Type__c == ‘return'){
            if(boughtPrice == null){
                return ‘boughtPrice is null';
            }
            Decimal updateBoughtAmount = boughtPrice - order.Total__c;
            if(updateBoughtAmount < 0){
                return ‘Bought price cannot be negative';
            }
            else {
                if(boughtPrice!= null){
                    boughtPrice = updateBoughtAmount;
                }
            }
        }
```

boughtPrice is brought from an api callout in my Orders Class:

```
 Decimal boughtPrice = Orders.grabBoughtPrice(order.Buyer__r.email);

 public static decimal grabBoughtPrice(string email){
    Decimal boughtPrice;
    String endpoint ='endpoint url here';
    String token = 'token';
    Http http=new Http();
    HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setHeader('auth', token);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    HttpResponse response=http.send(request);
    if(response.getStatusCode()==200)
    {
        boughtprice bp = (BoughtPrice) Json.deserialize(response.getBody(),BoughtPrice.class);
        boughtprice = decimal.valueOf(boughtPrice);
    }
    else{
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'No bought price');
        APexPages.addMessage(msg);
    }
    return boughtprice;
}
```

}

My ordersClass, grabBoughtPrice will run the boughtPriceMock for tests:

```
 if(test.isRunningTest()) Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new 
 boughtPriceMock());
```

My Bought price mock:

```
@isTest
global class boughtPriceMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{ “bought_Price" : "5000" }');
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
}
```

}

When it is run in my test, the debug log shows:

```
|request|System.HttpRequest|true|false
23:13:55.136 (8786303993)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[45]|request|"System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=null, Method=null]”|0x74d0a310
```

Which fails the test because the boughtPrice is not being brought back from the mock.How can I bring back the boughtPrice in my mock for my tests?

Test class:

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new boughtPriceMock());
    Test.startTest();

        Orders.grabBoughtPrice(order.Buyer__r.Email);
    Test.StopTest();
```

Comment: Is this a REST call out, or a web service callout? They are two different things.

Comment: It is a webservice class that invokes the rest get callout grabBoughtPrice in it..

Comment: Was the Orders class generated from a WSDL, though? Does it specifically make use of the code `WebServiceCallout.invoke` method anywhere in it?

Comment: It does not at all. It just sets the variable, bought price ,by setting it from the orders.grabboughtprice

Comment: What does Orders.grabBoughtPrice do, though? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: It grabs the bought price of an order from an external source, so it calls out to an endpoint by matching  an orders buyer email to grab bought price. Its a rest "get" method. Sorry for the english not sure if that makes sense

Comment: I have updated my question with the grabboughtprice method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpResponse response= new HttpResponse();
if(!test.isRunningTest()){
    response=http.send(request);
}
```

You're never calling your mock, because you specifically never call http.send when you're running a unit test. Instead, change your code to just:

```
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

The point of using a callout mock is to have your live code operate as normal, but intercept the callout with code that you write on your own (the mock).

---

```
if(test.isRunningTest()) Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new boughtPriceMock());
```

This code should be (without the if statement), in your unit test method, not in your live code, as mentioned in 朱保田's answer.

As a best practice, do **not** use Test.isRunningTest unless the documentation specifically states that you must do so to avoid a unit test error.

Comment: Hi thank you for your input but after making the changes i get this error: "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts" i also updated my post as well.

Comment: You're trying to cover `updateBoughtPrice`, right? Why are you calling `grabBoughtPrice` directly, then? Also, you should set the mock after Test.startTest(), but before calling your method.

Comment: Ah yes I removed it, the problem was that my test was failing because in my mock my "setBody" was not bringing back the right boughtPrice, I had to increase the boughtPrice so it wasn't coming in null

Answer (score -1):

`Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new 
 boughtPriceMock());` should be written in the test class

Comment: It is still coming back: VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[45]|request|System.HttpRequest|true|false
00:37:33.829 (11289657108)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[45]|request|"System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=null, Method=null]"|0x2f1e6998